# Jquery Full Calendar EventClick & UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I am working with the jquery full calendar plugin and running into to some issues with the ui dialog box. Right now, I when i click the event it will render the event and all the details about the event in the UI dialog box with no issues. However, when I close this box all other jquery events will stop on the page unless I refresh the page. I can click on other events, but no other jquery events on the page work... Here is my code.

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    if (event.url) {
        $('#myDialog').load('full_calendar/ajax/show_event.php?EventID=' + event.id).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            height: 450,
            modal: true,
            close: function(ev, ui) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });

        $('#myDialog').dialog('open');

        return false;
    }
},
```

I just cannot seem to figure this out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it is just a copy/paste error, but you seem to be missing a close bracket for `if(event.url) {`

Comment: Really? I think that is right after the return false; Just missing a ; I think. I am thinking the issue is the dialog is not getting killed after the close...Who knows, I am baffled.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.  In my mind, `dialog` had an open bracket after it.  Nothing to see here... move along.

Answer (score 2):

How do you close the dialog ?

I see you do: `$(this).hide();`

The dialog is a modal so the plugin creates an overlay underneath, to forbid manipulating the UI underneath. Even if this overlay is *invisible* (no opacity style), it is still going to do that.

Proper way to close the dialog is:

```
$(this).dialog('close'); // assuming 'this' is '#myDialog'
```

Comment: Yea, it still doesn't work even with 'close' . I have ven tried removing. Only thing that happens is the load portion gets removed and not the outer dialog.

Comment: I actually don't really get this phrase of yours: "I can click on other events, but no other jquery events on the page work". Can you maybe publish you page somewhere to be able to see it in action ?

Comment: Sorry it just means that I can click on an event from this event source close it with the "X" and then open another event from the same event source. But then no other "jquery event listeners" work on the page..ie add new event ui dialog, toggle, autocomplete, etc

Comment: You mean, the dialog is open and no other click works behind the dialog ? Check in the console if the element ".ui-widget-overlay" (before /BODY) is somehow visible or not

Comment: Well the modal you create is modal (model: true), it means there is an overlay behind it, blocking all clicks under the dialog.

Comment: Solved the issue.  Within the load page, the latest.j-query.js was included on the page and should not have been.